# How to move the changes from one branch to another branch git?

Tags: git

How can I move my work and changes from the `master` branch to a newly created branch and leave the master branch intact after the move?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can create a new branch pointing to the *current* commit using `git branch branchname` (or `git checkout -b branchname` if you want to check it out directly). This will basically duplicate your master branch, so you can continue working on there.

If you have successfully copied the branch, you can reset `master` to its original point by using `git reset --hard commit` where `commit` is the hash of the commit that should be the last one on master.

So for example you have a situation like this:

```
---- 1 ---- 2 ---- 3 ---- 4 ---- 5 ---- 6
                   ^                    ^
              original                master
            master commit
```

So you have checked out `master` on commit `6`, and you want to create a new branch `ticket` pointing to that `6` while resetting `master` to `3`:

```
git branch ticket
git reset --hard 3
git checkout ticket
```

And then you’re on `ticket` pointing to commit `6`, while `master` points to `3`.

Comment: That will work if your new branch is supposed to come out of `master`. If you need it on a different line of development, you'll have to look into [git-rebase](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-rebase)

Comment: The `-b` in `git checkout` tells Git to create the branch before checking it out. It’s basically a shortcut to `git branch name` and `git checkout name`; you usually use it when you want to start working on a new branch for something.

Comment: it looks like creating the new branch did not bring over the changes I had originaly made to master. not a big deal in my situation but it'd be good to know for the future....

Comment: What do you mean? If you create a branch, it should point to HEAD (if you don’t specify a different commit). So if you are on master (and have everything committed), then creating a new branch should get you to the same commit.

Comment: hm...i might not have committed before making the new branch/switching.

Comment: If you didn’t commit anything yet, you can use `git stash` to save your work for somewhere else.

Comment: @poke, How can I check what commit master in on?

Comment: @adrianmann `git show master` will tell you what commit `master` is pointing at.

Comment: I had this situation. I made patches from the commits I needed to move and then just applied them onto the proper branch and then reset the one they shouldn't have been in.

Answer (score 204):

**If the changes are not commited.**

you can stash the changes in the master branch .

```
git stash
```

then checkout the branch

```
git checkout -b newbranchname
```

and pop the changes here

```
git stash pop
```

**If the changes are commited :**

then create a branch :

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

checkout back to master branch:

```
git checkout master
```

reset to previous commit :

```
git reset --hard head^1
```

**PS**: This only works if no new files have been created and just the existing files are modified

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as OP does not specify that work has been committed

Comment: This works great, but I'm not sure what **git stash** and **git stash pop** are or what they're for. I'm a little perplexed.

Comment: @EdisonPebojot git stash is for saving the changes done after the last commit and git stash pop is to bring back those changes to the workspace.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, I had no commits. The goof I make most often with git is forgetting to start a new branch.

Answer (score 6):

If you have commit (say) 2 times after you realised you should have been in a branch then simply do

```
git branch work_branch
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

replace the 2 with the number of commits back you want to go. You'll still be on master at this point, if you want to move to the branch to continue work, just `git checkout work_branch`

see `git rev-parse --help` if you want to understand the syntax for how to traverse back up your commit tree with references like `HEAD~2`

Comment: Hi @Mark Fisher, what do you mean by "2 times"?

Comment: @adrianmann - I mean if you do 2 separate bits of work, adding changes and committing each of them, so your history looks like Start -> A -> B, where A and B are the 2 commits.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this problem by the following approach

**Step 1:** Create a new branch from the infected `master` branch and named it something like that `master_infected` ;

**Step 2:** now `hard reset` the infected `master` branch for removing the polluted `commits`  by

```
 git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

*(going back two `commits` before `HEAD` because for my case I have that two polluted `commits`. so for your case it may be different )*

Now my `master_infected` branch is containing whose code which I want to preserve *(As I said my polluted code)* and the `master` branch is now in a save mode.

Answer (score 2):

Create a **new** branch from where you should have, and then cherry pick the changes on the incorrect branch into the new branch.

You can then delete the **bad** branch, assuming you haven't pushed it elsewhere and other changes have been made against it.

Answer (score -1):

```
git add --all
git commit -m <commit-message>
git branch -m master <feature-branch-name>
git push --set-upstream origin <feature-branch-name>
```